# Is "may or may not" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

(Note: I'm ***not*** talking about the same kind of redundancy as in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/is-the-expression-may-or-may-not-semantically-void) question).

Is "may or may not" correct, or is it a redundant version of "may or not"? I've seen both, and I don't know which one(s) is (are?) correct:

- [The position of lecturer is occasionally given to individuals [...] who may or not have a doctoral degree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#University)
- The position of lecturer is occasionally given to individuals [...] who may or may not have a doctoral degree.

Comment: I thought that may, alone, suggests that something is uncertain. So if one says "the people that are attending may be dressed in formal attire", it is obvious that it implies that they may not be so attired. This kind of sentence is very commonly written with "may or may not", which seems to me redundant. I think that jpwat's comment "the implication..." was incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take the phrase as a whole idiom—rather that the sum of its parts—it is not redundant. The point of its use is to highlight a common assumption that does not apply. In your example, it could be assumed that a lecturer would need a doctoral degree, and the idiom dispels this notion.

Answer (score 8):

If I read "may or not", I would suppose that it was an error. I am startled to find that other people find it acceptable. (UK English, in case that is relevant).

Comment: I agree! (USA here.) I can hardly think of how to use "may or not" - maybe something like "Are you going?" "I may. _shrug_ Or not."

Comment: Would parens help here? "The lecturer may have (or not) a doctoral degree."

Answer (score 2):

The "may or not" version generates problems like: "He must do what he may or not a thing will come of it" vs. "He says he will fish; he may or not like the experience."  You have to read on too far into the sentence to resolve whether the "or not" goes with the "may" or the rest of the text.

Perhaps because of this, the form I've heard most often is "may or may not" (which requires more exotic conditions before it becomes difficult to parse).

If you make the verb explicit: "may fish or not", then the "or not" form is quite common also.

Answer (score 1):

*May or may not* is redundant; *may or not* is indecipherable; *may* by itself communicates both possibilities. In this instance, the idea of *may* is not relevant. “The position of lecturer is occasionally given to individuals [...] who *do not* have a doctoral degree.”  Which implies that, most of the time, the position is given to individuals who *do* have a doctoral degree. This is more straightforward.

Comment: The implication you suggest is not supported by the passage, @David.  It could mean the opposite: "The position is never given to individuals who DO have a doctoral degree."

Answer (score 0):

I think both usages are correct. In the US, it's far more common to hear "may or may not". The extra "may" might feel too wordy for some, but because I'm used to hearing it "may or not" sounds very uneven to me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is the same as it was in the [other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28007/may-or-may-not-redundancy/124458) - that is to say, the certainty is unknown, which is why an apparent 'double modifier' is needed.  In your case, the lecture being given may be attended by those with doctorate degrees, OR it may not.  THe lecturer does not know, and their uncertainty about this is reflected in the construct "may or may not".

"May or not" doesn't quite work, because it would imply *certainty* that at least one individual does not have a doctorate degree where there is not any.